# While trying to enable epel I somehow broke my repolist

Tags: fedora, epel

I originally posted this on stack overflow and was told this was the better place to ask:

I made the attempt at enabling EPEL on my Fedora 22 machine by running

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
```

Then

```
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
```

And now when I run

```
dnf repolist
```

I get the following

```
[sinux1@horrible-host ~]$ sudo dnf repolist
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64  1.8 MB/s | 9.0 MB     00:05    
Failed to open: /var/cache/dnf/epel-2b6dfc5904c26562/repodata/49c4e3bd54f19136521be9b254830c954369cc22ce1b661db502ebef13b0004c-updateinfo.xml.bz2.
[sinux1@horrible-host ~]$
```

I'm stuck and not sure what my next step is. How can I reverse what I did, and what would have been the proper way of enabling EPEL? Thanks for any input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EPEL is for RHEL and CentOS, and not Fedora. In your case, you've tried to install EPEL for EL7, on Fedora 22.

DNF is doing exactly what it should, you've basically installed a repo which isn't designed to be run on Fedora 22.

edit: Forgot to add, you might want to remove that repo now with

```
rpm -e epel-release
```

or

```
dnf remove epel-release
```